# How to point correct path in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have .sln file and Dockerfile at a different location on my local hard drive.

Till now I work on a source code where .sln file and Dockerfile are present at the same location.

I am facing difficulty to configure it correctly.

- I have .sln file at the location `CompanyCarsDocker\CompanyCarsDocker\CompanyCarsDocker.sln`
- And My Dockerfile is present inside `CompanyCarsDocker\CompanyCarsDocker\CarApi\Dockerfile`
  -

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 54411

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./*.sln ./
ADD ./site /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ./CarApi.csproj CarApi/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/CarApi
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM builder AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c  Release -o /app

FROM base AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CarApi.dll"]
```

I have added `ADD ./site /inetpub/wwwroot` for testing purpose. I am getting

`ADD failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder782713904\site: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Same error I am also Getting at `COPY ./CarApi.csproj CarApi/`

Please let me know if I configured something wrong in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the -f flag of `docker build` to specify the path to the Dockerfile

Make sure you’re current working directory is the one which has the sln file and rest of the project. Run the command `docker build -f <path to Dockerfile> .`

Comment: I need to give the path in Dockerfile at `COPY *.sln ./`. At this location I am getting `COPY failed: no source files were specified`

Comment: I have Changed to `COPY . ./*.sln ./` and this worked

Comment: As far as I know this should work. Did you make sure to keep the directory containing the sln file as the working directory?

Comment: @E_FreeLancer don’t you mean “COPY ./*.sln ./“? I think you’ve added an extra “.”

Comment: `COPY ./*.sln ./` wont work as the .sln file is present in  **CompanyCarsDocker** while Dockerfile is presnt in  **CompanyCarsDocker\CarApi\**

Answer (score 0):

your .sln file is two directories up so you should use

```
COPY ../../*.sln ./
```

instead of

```
COPY . ./*.sln ./
```